# Session Abandoned

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

I have a problem about session in my ASP.NET Web App. When i write my username and password and clicked login button, session is abandoned.
In my web.config, i use :

sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20"

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: For `InProc` mode, you don't need `stateConnectionString` or `sqlConnectionString` attributes - those are used for `StateServer` and `SQLServer` modes, respectively - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx. You'll need to elaborate on what it is you're doing (perhaps show some code) as your question is quite vague at the moment

Comment: I know that but i don't know what should i do for my session problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Session is Abandoned"? How do you know is abandoned?

Comment: if you have any idea please tell or please silence :)

Comment: sorry lcarus, i wrote this russ cam, the session is abondoned and returned login page

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use **stateConnectionString** and **sqlConnectionString** attributes if you are going to store session in asp.net process.

Just write sessionState mode="InProc".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I used <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/> but still session is abandoned :(